# GRAVE: Error Rendering View cannot convert String to integer custom filter Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, filtering, jsf-2.2

I want to filter a column using custom filter. the type of column is String

my page index.xhtml is like:

```
<p:dataTable id="tab" var="v" value="#{registerVehicule.listVehicules}" filteredValue="#{registerVehicule.filteredV}"
            selection="#{registerVehicule.selectedV}" rowKey="#{v.idVehicule}" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="500" widgetVar="tabs">

            <f:facet name="header">
                Liste des vehicules  
            </f:facet>

            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center">
            </p:column>

            <p:column  sortBy="#{v.shipmentDate}" width="140" filterBy="#{v.shipmentDate}"
                filterFunction="registerVehicule.shipmentFilter">
                <f:facet name="filter">
                    <h:inputText id="filterId" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{v.shipmentDate}" />
                <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel value="Shipment Date"></h:outputLabel>
                <br/>
                de:                     <p:calendar id="from" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" styleClass="shipmentFilter">
                        <p:ajax event="dateSelect"
                            onstart="$(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('#{p:component('filterId')}'))[0].value = $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('#{p:component('from')}_input'))[0].value + '-' + $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('#{p:component('to')}_input'))[0].value"
                            oncomplete="PF('tabs').filter()" />
                    </p:calendar>
                    à : 
                    <p:calendar id="to" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" styleClass="shipmentFilter">
                        <p:ajax event="dateSelect"
                            onstart="$(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('#{p:component('filterId')}'))[0].value = $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('#{p:component('from')}_input'))[0].value + '-' + $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('#{p:component('to')}_input'))[0].value"
                            oncomplete="PF('tabs').filter()" />
                    </p:calendar>
                </f:facet></p:column>
....
</p:datatable
```

and the method in managedBean:

```
public void shipmentFilter() {
    System.out.println("from:");
}
```

but i got this error:

> 

```
GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @94,55 filterFunction="registerVehicule.shipmentFilter": Cannot convert registerVehicule.shipmentFilter of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Integer
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.filter(FilterFeature.java:154)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.encode(FilterFeature.java:105)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:77)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:559)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:692)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:399)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:319)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1896)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:425)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

mars 23, 2015 4:21:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet Faces Servlet a généré une exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.startCDATA(HtmlResponseWriter.java:681)
    at javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper.startCDATA(ResponseWriterWrapper.java:179)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startError(PartialResponseWriter.java:341)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startError(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:174)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:202)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:126)
    at javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone help me ?? i'm using Primefaces 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need the right method signature. From the [Primefaces user guide](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html):

> filterFunction should be a method with three parameters; column value,
>   filter value and locale. Return value is a boolean, true accepts the
>   value and false rejects it.
>
> ```
> public boolean filterByPrice(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {
>   //return true or false
> }
> ```